# Make an error to pop-up without refresh

Tags: php, forms, refresh, detection, subscribe

I have this php code, which basically checks if the e-mail is correct and if it is, it saves the e-mail in a *.txt file (I'm using it for a subscribe form), if it's not it pop-ups an error div, but it pops it up with refreshing the whole web page, and when it's in the bottom you have to scroll to actually see the error.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    if( isset($_POST['inputEmail']) ) {
        $email = trim($_POST['inputEmail']);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo "<div class='wrong'>This e-mail is invalid.</div>";
        }
        else {
            $data = $email . "\n";
            $ret = file_put_contents('emailAddresses.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            if ( $ret !== FALSE ) {
                header('Location: thanks.html');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is send your request with AJAX using javascript or jQuery.

With JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               //Request worked, Do something
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400')
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
           }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(){
      $(this).addClass("done");
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is I'm a graphic designer doing it for a personal project. Is there any chance you could make it with the php or I can get a programmer, but It won't be fast.